# How can I make Virtual Box sees my external hard drive

Tags: macos, mac, ubuntu-9.10, virtualbox

I have:

- installed Virtual Box 3.1.2 on Mac OS X 10.5
- setup a Ubuntu 9.10 machine for Virtual Box
- have a new external USB hard drive

My question is what can I format my hard drive and configure my Virtual box so that my ubuntu machine can read/write to that drive?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a filter for the USB device (same on Mac OS X):

[image]

Ubuntu should be able to see the drive already.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to create a new shared folder in the VM's settings and map the shared folder to the external drive's root directory; this has the benefit that the Ubuntu install inside the VM will have read/write access to the drive no matter what filesystem it's formatted with.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is what can I format my
>   hard drive and configure my Virtual
>   box so that my ubuntu machine can
>   read/write to that drive?

Out of the box, the only commonly supported file systems between host and guest would be FAT32 and HFS (but you can add [ext2/ext3](http://www.dailyblogged.com/1085/add-ext2-support-to-os-x/)/[NTFS](http://blog.julipedia.org/2007/03/ntfs-readwrite-support-for-mac-os-x.html) support to Mac OS X).

If you stick with FAT32 (for windows-compatibility reasons) keep in mind that the maximum file size is limited to 4 GB (minus 1 byte).

Comment: HFS already works fine in Ubuntu.

Comment: ...although HFS+ does not have write capabilities in Ubuntu :)